# How to generate keys and save them to an external file?

Tags: bash, openssl, ubuntu-18.04

I try to generate with OpenSSL a peer of key.

```
userner@userner-VirtualBox:/certs$ openssl genrsa 2048 >frugalCA.key
```

However, the output can not be generated in  this file frugalCA.key and I got  this error:

```
bash: frugalCA.key: Permission denied
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me pleaz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me with this command line:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 | sudo tee  frugalCA.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **-out** flag:

`openssl genrsa -out frugalCA.key 2048`

But from the output shown, you probably don't have the write permission in that folder.

Comment: It gives me this error: "genrsa: Can't open "frugalCA.key" for writing, Permission denied"

Comment: I edited my anwser. It's a permission issue in the folder you're trying to write to.

Comment: Yes I am trying to write the file. Could help me please ? Should I add  -w as an option to allow  that? In fact I am trying to create the file and to redirect the result in that file? even when adding sudo It does not work.

Comment: You can try to direct the output to a file that is in your home directory or a temporary folder: openssl genrsa -out /tmp/frugalCA.key 2048 or openssl genrsa -out ~/frugalCA.key 2048

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specific on where you want your output, as the default location may be restricted.

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>openssl genrsa -out C:\Users\user123\Downloads\MyOrganization_auth.key 2048
```